# What path will air take to leave the space station?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, vacuum, flow, air

[image: Space Station]

Hi everyone,
lets say we have a circle shaped space station and there was an accident where we got a hole (hole A on the picture) on a station and now most of the station is vacuum except for one enclosed part that is still filled with air. Now if we make holes B and C at the same time in the enclosed part, what will then happen with the air? Will it:

1. because air moves in random directions, half of the air will go through hole B and then through hole A and other half will go through hole C, go through entire station and then through hole A
2. because of difference in pressure all air will go through hole B and then through hole A (I am not sure if this is true or I am misremembering, but I read somewhere that air takes the shortest path to equalize pressure so that is the reason that all air will go through hole B? If this is not the true is there some way to influence all of the air to go through hole B, change the size of the holes, make a longer distance between holes C and A?)
3. this and next scenarios are highly unlikely but I have left them just to cover all possibilities , all of air will go through hole C and then through hole A
4. air will stay where it is and it will not leave the room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above. Assuming all three holes are of the same size, air in the chamber will flow through both holes B and C to equalize the pressure in the space station, but at different rates. This is because hole A causes air to flow out of the station, and therefore the air pressure on the B side will equalize less rapidly than on the C side. The difference in rates will be determined by several factors, including the relative volumes of the space station and of the chamber, the size of the holes and the initial air pressure in the chamber. But in the end, all these considerations are moot: pretty soon there will be no air in there and everyone will suffocate to death. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer: none of the above. More than half, but less than all, of the air will go through B; the remainder will go through C. That is assuming the sizes of the holes are the same.

As it is a multiple choice question you need to answer option 1, as you could adjust the sizes of the holes to make this option true. The other three are all certainly false.

The quickest way to equalise the pressure is for the air to leave though *both* holes at the same time. The only way to prevent air escaping through hole C is to plug it. Even having another room behind it would not stop air leaving the aired room through C, though in this case that air would flow back through C, B and A later in the process.